# Wagtail-2fa token doesn't work when setting up 2fa after new admin user registration

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

New users can't seem to set up 2fa--token always fails at set up with wagtail-2fa.

**Background:**

I set up a wagtail site a few months ago with Wagtail-2fa (which is based on django-otp). When I first set up an admin user with 2fa, the token works fine. That admin login has no problems using 2fa. When I try to set up new users, I can register the user, but when the user logs in for the first time, it requires 2fa set up (which is the desired behavior) but the token always fails.

I've tried Google Authenticator, Symantec VIP, and Duo Mobile. None of them work for new users. Wagtail-2fa uses TOTP so I checked the time on the device and on the server and they appear to match at least to the minute. I've tried the same process on my localhost, staging, and production (the latter two on heroku), and none of them work (but the original admin with 2fa works).

My main hypothesis now is that something broke with wagtail-2fa when I upgraded several packages:

- django 3.1.11 --> 4.0.5
- wagtail 2.15.1 --> 3.0.1

It could be that wagtail-2fa doesn't support wagtail 3.0.1 or django 4.0.5. I'm going to clone a commit prior to the upgrade to see if that's the cause of the problem. If it is, does anyone have ideas on how to patch wagtail-2fa or if there are other django 2fa packages that work with django 4.0 and wagtail 3.0? Any other ideas to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

This pull request from wagtail-2fa fixed the issue:
[middleware fix](https://github.com/labd/wagtail-2fa/pull/179)